# How to open Internal Links (label links) in same tab in google blogger

Tags: html, blogger

My blog url: https://fashionindiar.blogspot.com

I am unable to open the label links on my stand alone home page, in the same tab / window. Actually, by mistake I checked the respective checkbox under the Link button on menu bar earlier, after which I am unable to revert. However, the checkbox shows unchecked.

Also, please note that I have Social Media buttons on my home page, which should open in new tab / window (I have already activated the respective option under Link button, and I don't want to tamper with it).

Please help me to open all label links (on my home page) in the same tab / window, and not in any new one.

Looking forward to your reply.

Thank you.

Shampa Sengupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open links in the same frame as it was clicked remove the attribute `target="_blank"` from `<a>` tags or change it to `target="_self"`

Comment: Appreciate your kind help. Thank you.

Comment: If it solved the problem, please mark it  as an accepted solution to help other user solve similar issues.